# multi row "dual" table in mysql/sql

Tags: mysql, optimization

This is an extension of the "dual" table concept (temporary table created on the fly for one query and discarded straight after)

I am trying to join a multi row `dual` table with another one, so as to avoid to have to run the same query several times with different parameters, using 1 statement.

One of the issue I am having is that union is very slow for dual tables, and I am unaware of any more efficient way to accomplish the following. (100 ms when joining 50 dual together)

```
SELECT
  b.id,
  b.ref_unid,
  a.date
  FROM
    (
    SELECT
      'b8518a84-c501-11dd-b0b6-001d7dc91168'  as unid,
      '2010-01-05' as date
   UNION
    SELECT
      'b853a1f2-c501-11dd-b0b6-001d7dc91168',
      '2010-01-06'
   UNION
    SELECT
      'b8557bd0-c501-11dd-b0b6-001d7dc91168',
      '2010-01-07'
   /* ... */
  ) as a
  join other_table b
      ON
      b.ref_unid = a.unid
```

Is there another way of accomplishing this goal?

Is there any syntax similar to that of insert into values statement that would accomplish that goal, such as:

```
SELECT
  unid,
  id
  FROM
    (
      WITH (unid, date) USING VALUES
      (
        ('b8518a84-c501-11dd-b0b6-001d7dc91168','2010-01-05'),
        ('b853a1f2-c501-11dd-b0b6-001d7dc91168','2010-01-06'), 
        ('b8557bd0-c501-11dd-b0b6-001d7dc91168','2010-01-07'),
         /* ... */
      )
    ) as a
  join other_table b
      ON
      b.ref_unid = a.unid
```

I'm looking for a 1-statement solution. Multiple trips to the database aren't possible.

Answer (score 1):

There's no other convention I'm aware of that's available in MySQL to construct a derived table in a single statement.  If this dealt with a single column, at ~50 values it could be converted to use an `IN` clause.

The best performing approach is to load the data into a table of one form or another -- in MySQL, for a temporary use I'd recommend using the MEMORY engine.  At ~50 tuples, I have to wonder why the data isn't already in the database...

Comment: The API I am coding for allows to pass a list of tuples and returns a list of objects for each of these tuples.
Since the number of tuples passed in is typically around 10-50, I am trying to avoid calling one query 50 times , just changing a couple of parameters.

I tried using the multiple IN statement, but it doesn't use any of the existing indexes, unlike the approach above that is very fast apart from union of dual tables.